# My Sony Vaio VGN-N31M/W will not boot without the power cable plugged in

Tags: boot, power-management, vaio, acpi

My Sony Vaio VGN-N31M/W only boots with the power cable plugged in.

The screen simply hangs on the Grub screen, it loads when acpi is disabled but the laptop is then very slow and can not recognise the battery.

Has anybody had similar issues, what would the steps be to debug the issue?

EDIT:

This is now fixed, I added "acpi_osi=" , it turns out my laptop was intended to work with Vista, which added some weird ACPI settings.

I found the answer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)

"acpi_osi= doesnt disable turn off all acpi functions. It just makes the kernel not pretend its windows to the acpi bios and that can avoid problems with bioses where windows errata are fixed in BIOS for a specific windows OS (by default Linux will pretend to be any Windows version). More details here:

ftp://ftp.suse.com/pub/people/trenn/...or_vendors.pdf

adding acpi_osi= commonly fixes problems with LCD backlight, due to a bug in vista that vendors "fixed" in the bios."